# FileInputStream not reading file after packaging

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

Okay so I'm fiddling with this ancient, decrepit RSPS server as a way to learn and whatnot.

Anyway, I packaged the server, everything works and it runs in eclispe and everything, but when I try to run the server from a .bat file it is unable to load the .ini file in the main directory.

The run.bat:

```
@echo off
cd bin
java -Xmx256M com/devolution/core/Server
pause
```

the packaging:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSIRP.png

What I need is to understand why server.ini is loaded when the server is run in eclipse, but not via a .bat file. All of my data files are having the same issue.

Let me know if there's any other info you need :D

Edit: Obviously I have the path wrong, but I'm just not quite sure what I should be editing it to in order to read a file out of a different directory

No stop guys I'm not jarring anything, nothing is being jarred. It's not a problem of reading a file from a jar, I'm never going to jar it. It's not an issue like that.

Comment: You don't load files from a jar like this. Use `.getResource{,AsStream}()`.

Comment: It's not a jar, and never will be

Comment: your problem with resources is when you export the file as jar?

Comment: um no I'm not jarring anything. nothing is being jarred.

Answer (score 0):

I was using cd bin in my bat file, and server.ini was outside of that. whoops.